# Core Data sorting numeric values using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: core-data, ios6, nssortdescriptor

I have a set of core data items that I want to sort based on a numeric attribute that I have set to Integer 16. It's just a list of things that have a custom sort so I've added an 'ordering' integer so that I can say abc->1 cba->2 aaa->3 etc. I want to sort using the 1,2,3 and display the key (which is another attribute).

I can't figure out how to do this, I'm guessing I need to change the selector but I don't know what to do.

```m
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ordering" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
```

The error I get is

```m
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8142450'
```

I am creating the core data attribute like this:

```m
dataItemOne.ordering = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ordering" 
                                  ascending:YES]];
```

do the job?

Comment: Haha yes it works with that now, I'm sure I tried that before and it didn't work but I think I was getting another error. Brain dead today. Thanks for the help.